# Angular2: How to link directly from the root view to a (grand)child view

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I am experimenting with Angular 2 and have come across a problem I'm not sure how to debug.

**Example situation**

I have an `AppComponent` that handles all the base level routing, and each 'level' of routing down is declared on a new router for that level.

I have the following routes:

- /home , defined on `AppComponent`
- /applications , defined on `AppComponent`
- /applications/new , defined on `ApplicationRouterComponent`
- /applications/foo , defined on `ApplicationRouterComponent`

As part of the surrounding template, there is a nav bar that is common to all pages and so needs to be able to link to any routes defined in child routers. `[routerLink]`ing to a nested component doesn't cause any errors to be thrown.

**Problem**

When linking to a grandchild route, it doesn't appear that the View component is even constructed. i.e.,

`<a [routerLink]="['./ApplicationRouter/New']">New Application</a>`

The `ApplicationRouterComponent` gets constructed and displayed, but the `NewApplication` component does not.

**Code Sample**

appComponent.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {
  RouteConfig,
  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
} from 'angular2/router';
import {ApplicationRouterComponent} from './routes/application/applicationRouter';
import {HomeComponent} from './routes/home/homeComponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'bop-application',
  templateUrl: 'app/index.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/applications/...', name: 'ApplicationRouter', component: ApplicationRouterComponent }
])
export class AppComponent { }
```

./app/routes/application/applicationRouter

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {
  RouteConfig,
  ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
} from 'angular2/router';
import {NewApplicationComponent} from './new/newApplicationComponent';
import {FooComponent} from './new/foo';

@Component({
  selector: 'application-router',
  templateUrl: 'app/routes/application/index.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/new', name: 'New', component: NewApplicationComponent},
  { path: '/foo', name: 'Foo', component: FooComponent},
])
export class ApplicationRouter {
  constructor() {
    debugger;
  }
}
```

./app/index.html

```
<h1>Portal</h1>
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['./ApplicationRouter/New']">New Application</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

./app/application/index.html

```
Application Router
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

./app/application/new/new.html

```
<h4>New View</h4>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The router link should be

```
<a [routerLink]="['/ApplicationRouter', 'New']">New Application</a>
```

A router link takes a list of route names, not a path. There are some characters supported that are interpreted like in a path

- `/xxx` for starting at root router
- `..` for starting at the parent router
- `./xxx` for current router (AFAIK redundant)

Comment: Thanks for this. I updated to the above, but its still doesnt construct or render the component. In fact for some bizarre reason it generates the home component within the application router component.

It generates the URL correctly, I have noticed if I click once, it loads the ApplicationRouter component, and then clicking again actually changes the URL. But still doesn't render the grandchild component.

Comment: Don't add `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` on components - only in `bootstrap(...)`